# AudioManager restore default state/behaviour

Tags: android, android-audiomanager

I'm using `AudioManager` to switch handset/speaker mode with `setSpeakerphoneOn`.

AFAIK, this setting is global and affect all phone audio output state. Some apps by default are using handset mode, another speaker mode.

For example I have 3 apps YouTube (Y), WhatsApp (W) and MyApp (M).

**Default** audio outputs:

Y - speaker

W - handset (when outcoming call)

M - it's doesn't matter

When `setSpeakerphoneOn(true)` in M programmatically in apps Y, W sounds come from speaker. If I `setSpeakerphoneOn(false)` in M, Y, W sound comes from handset.

When I close M the sound in Y and W comes according to last setted boolean, and until I don't `Clear Data` in App Settings sound output doesn't works as it was **Default**

The question is: how to restore default state/behaviour after app closing ?

Comment: when do you want to restore the settings?

Comment: @greywolf82 when I close the app (I handle it)

Comment: by handset I mean front speaker

Comment: so what's the problem to restore in onDestroy()?

Comment: question is HOW?

Comment: did you try to use the setBluetoothScoOn to on?

Answer (score 0):

Late answer but might be useful to some.
You can simply restore your AudioManager mode to normal.

`audioManager.setMode(AudioManager.MODE_NORMAL);`